# Multiplying a member of a matrix in a struct by a float

Tags: c

I'm trying to multiply a member of a matrix in a struct and I get an error. This is the code:

```
typedef unsigned char   BYTE;

typedef struct {
    BYTE bMatrix[3][4];
} STRUCTURE;


STRUCTURE structure = FillStructure();

float myFloat = structure.bMatrix[1][1] * 0.1;
```

This last line gives me a 
invalid operands to binary * (have 'BYTE * {aka unsigned char *}' and 'float')

Thank you!!

Comment: cast the Matrix Element to float

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error: http://ideone.com/wxcUZg . Also the error message is not correct, `0.1` is a `double`, not a `float`. Is this your real code?

Comment: Your code compiles and runs perfectly with the strictest error checking level ([demo](http://ideone.com/pCy8Tq)). Voting to close as "cannot reproduce".

Comment: That's the real code. I'm using GCC compiler on LPCXpresso

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Why the quick vote to close response? Why not try and help figure out the problem? I'm sure the OP didn't just make up a question because they were bored.

Comment: @user2697817 A vote to close is not permanent. It serves as a way to tell OP that the question in its current form cannot be answered. Once OP edits to provide a broken code, the vote can be retracted.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight the code is not compiling. even if I change it to double myDouble = structure.bMatrix[1][1]; I'm getting this error: incompatible types when initializing type 'double' using type 'BYTE * {aka unsigned char *}'

Comment: @espeester Please click the demo link and see your program code that compiles and runs using a standard compiler. There is something in your actual code that is not shown in the question.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, is `FillStructure` a macro (as you say this is the real code)? It looks weird to me that you are trying to do these calculations out of a function, where it would be more appropriate, like:

```
typedef unsigned char BYTE;
typedef struct {
    BYTE bMatrix[3][4];
} STRUCTURE;

#define FillStructure() (STRUCTURE){{0}} /* i guess? */

int main(void)
{
    STRUCTURE structure = FillStructure();
    float myFloat = structure.bMatrix[1][1] * 0.1;
}
```

Then, as said in the comments, you should try to cast the matrix member in order to "convert" the value:

```
float myFloat = (float)structure.bMatrix[1][1] * 0.1;
```

Comment: Because OP's code compiles and runs (see ideone.com/wxcUZg ) the cast would only hide the real problem.